# Swift packages and conflicting dependencies

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

One of the most challenging tasks of every package manager I have seen is handling conflicting dependencies.

Let's work with the following imaginary application *SwiftApp*, which depends on some 3rd party packages.

`- SwiftApp
  - packageA@latest
    - packageC@1.0.0
    - packageD@latest
  - packageB@latest
    - packageC@2.0.0
    - packageE@latest`

From the dependency graph above, we can see that both of *SwiftApp*'s dependencies use *packageC*, but with different major version identifiers. For most language ecosystems, this becomes a problem - a major version bump usually means there have been made changes to the code which are not backwards-compatible with the previous major version.

Depending on technical capabilities of the language/compiler/other relevant component, the package manager can be implemented in one of the following ways:

1. Refuse to install/compile (php, ruby, python?, others?)
2. Don't care, let the developer deal with potential compiler errors (???)
3. Install *packageC* for both packages independently (Node.js, others?)

The third option can only be achieved with proper support by the language or compiler itself.

#### Can this dependency graph be achieved without breakage in Swift?

In other words, is it technically possible for *packageA* to have (and use)  version 1.0.0 of *packageC* while *packageB* will have version 2.0.0?

> Given the recent announcement of Swift being now open-source and coming with a package manager of its own, I think that this question might be very valuable for future readers interested in Swift package development.

Comment: Very interesting question. I would ask that question on the swift mail list.
https://lists.swift.org/mailman/listinfo/swift-build-dev

Swift support namespaces. It means Option 3 should be possible to implement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer:

Now it's option 2, fail to build.
It gives an error:  `swift-build: The dependency graph could not be satisfied`

It's because SPM is on very early stage of development, very early beta.
[Dependency Resolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageManagerCommunityProposal.md#dependency-resolution)

> The Swift Package Manager does not currently provide a mechanism for automatically resolving conflicts in a dependency tree. However, this will be provided in the future.

### Long answer:

Swift has namespaces. It means that `packageC` in `packageA` would have a full name `packageA.packageC`. And in `packageB` it would be `packageB.packageC`

Because of that, it is possible to have the same framework included more than once.
SPM also fetch dependencies with version suffix (packageC-1.0.0). So I think It should be possible to check what version is required in particular package and fetch it.

Also Swift supports Dynamic frameworks. It means that you can have many version of the same framework and they should not conflict with each other.

As I see it in the future it should be possible to have  **Option 3** (Install packageC for both packages independent) working.

**Summary:**

- Now: Option 2 - fail to build.
- Future: Option 3 - install both versions independently

Comment: Does anyone know if this has changed with the new version of spm shipping with Swift 4? I can't find a clear answer..

Comment: 5 years later it still hasn't changed.