# xCode SPM multiple targets named

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

In my project I have two dependencies

```
.package(name: "Web3swift", url: "https://github.com/skywinder/web3swift.git", from: "3.0.6"),
.package(name: "Random", url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/random.git", .upToNextMinor(from: "1.2.0"))
```

the Random package also has `Core` dependencies (https://github.com/vapor/core.git), and the target package name `Web3swift` also has `Core` in it

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Web3swift",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v10_15), .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "web3swift", targets: ["web3swift"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt.git", .upToNextMinor(from: "5.3.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift.git", .upToNextMinor(from: "1.5.1"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "secp256k1"),
        .target(
            name: "Core",
            dependencies: ["BigInt", "secp256k1", "CryptoSwift"]
        ),
        .target(
            name: "web3swift",
            dependencies: ["Core", "BigInt", "secp256k1"],
            exclude: excludeFiles,
            resources: [
                .copy("./Browser/browser.js"),
                .copy("./Browser/browser.min.js"),
                .copy("./Browser/wk.bridge.min.js")
            ]
        ),
```

Now I have a problem:

```
multiple targets named 'Core' in: 'core', 'web3swift'; consider using the `moduleAliases` parameter in manifest to provide unique names
```

Can you please explain how to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0339-module-aliasing-for-disambiguation.md ?

Comment: Please explain the `target(name: "Core", dependencies: []` - part. Do you also want to have a target called "Core"?

Comment: @baronfac no, I just want install `Web3swift` library and `Random` library, but I get the error

Comment: @Larme I tried 
        `.target(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Random", package: "Random", moduleAliases: ["Core": "SCore"]),
                .product(name: "web3swift", package: "Web3swift")
            ]
        ),`

but get a error 'product(name:package:moduleAliases:condition:)' is unavailable

Comment: let me write out a full answer

Comment: The only solution I found might be these options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797358/swift-package-resolution-failed-because-multiple-targets-named-a-same-framework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift Package Resolution failed because multiple targets named a same framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797358/swift-package-resolution-failed-because-multiple-targets-named-a-same-framework)

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the [developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/package/dependency/modulealiases), you'll note that this is only supported in Swift `5.7+`. To fix the "...is unavailable" message, you'll need to update the header in `Package.swift` to: `// swift-tools-version:5.7` (also requires XCode > 14).

For full details, you can refer to:

1. The Swift 5.7 [release notes](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-5.7-released/)
2. The evolution proposal: [SE-0339](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0339-module-aliasing-for-disambiguation.md)

AFAICT, your changes look correct.